# Looping over arrays, and checking if it has values

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Currently I'm checking over **$countrySelected** to see if there is a match against the list of **$countries** array.  I need this so I can echo out the option html as selected.

This is quite expensive with using **in_array()**, especially when the **countries** array is bigger. I'm hoping there is a more efficient way of checking?

Appreciate the help!

---

**The current code**

```
foreach ( $arr as $k => $v ){ // See output of $arr below

    $countrySelected[$k] = $mfwp_options_data[$k]['brand'][$v->post_name]['country'];

    foreach ($countries as $key => $val) {
       if ( in_array($val, $countrySelected[$k]) ) {
           echo "<option value='" . $val . "' selected>" . $val . "</option>";
       } else {
           echo "<option value='" . $val . "'>" . $val . "</option>";
       }
    }
}
```

**$countries** array sample:

```
Array
(
    [AF] => Afghanistan
    [AX] => Aland Islands
    [AL] => Albania
    [DZ] => Algeria
)
```

**$countrySelected** array sample:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Afghanistan
            [1] => Albania
            [2] => Antarctica
            [3] => Botswana
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Afghanistan
            [1] => Aland Islands
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Afghanistan
            [1] => Aland Islands
            [2] => Albania
        )
)
```

**$arr** output from wordpress

```
Array
[0] => stdClass Object
(
    [ID] => 12
    [post_name] => brand-example
    [post_status] => publish
    [post_title] => Brand Example
)
```

**$mfwp_options_data** is the option array from wordpress, its output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [brand] => Array
                (
                    [brand-example] => Array
                        (
                            [total] => 7
                            [country] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Afghanistan
                                    [1] => Aland Islands
                                 )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: And you think iterating through multiple `foreach` loops and `if` statements isn't expensive?

Comment: I'm aware, but I can't see another way of getting to the result I want. If you have any suggestions please push me in a direction - thank you!

Comment: I do have a suggestion: this is not the area of your code you'd want to spend time optimizing. It has little or no effect even if you're dealing with an array of hundreds of elements.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't help much does it.